# Returning a value from a method and storing it into an Array for use on another method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an method getDiff() in a class called Computation that computes the difference between two values and returns the absolute value of the result as shown below:

```
public int getDiff() {
    Computation amg = new Computation();

    setTemp = 55;
    dT      = (actualMouldTemp - setTemp);
    AMT     = (int) Math.abs(dT);
    System.out.println("The temperature difference is : "+ AMT);

    return AMT;
}
```

I want the value `AMT` returned to be stored in an `Array` then used in further calculations for heating time as as shown below:

```
public double getHeatingTime1() {
    Controller jose    = new Controller();
    int[]      Results = new int[4];
    //Results [] = new int[4];
    //Results [] = Computation.class;

    Q      = 3; //heating in kW
    Cp     = 4.2; //Specific heat capacity of water
    volume = 6; 

    //AMT = 
    System.out.println("AMT IS " + Results[1]);
    long HT1 = (long) ((volume * Cp * Results[1]) / Q);

    return HT1;
}
```

The problem is that I created an array that stores these results but I am failing to see the value of `Results[1]` in the method `getHeatingTime1()` as it is giving me a zero as my heating time and on the print line. How best do I represent such an `Array` in my code? Thank you

I am using the class Computation as the class that handles all calculation for my JADE agents. So what happens is that the values used in getDiff() for the actualMouldTemp is a value returned by the method getAnswer() as show below:

```
public double getAnswer() {

      TemperatureControlAgent ta = new TemperatureControlAgent();
      TemperatureControlAgent.CoolingOrdersServer lp = ta.new CoolingOrdersServer();

        int rand1[] = new int[3];

        RandomVariableGenerator var = new RandomVariableGenerator();
        rand1 = RandomVariableGenerator.getRand();

       meltTemp = 245;
       setTemp = 55;
        System.out.println("Melt Temp is  : "+ meltTemp);
        //System.out.println("Melt Temp is  : "+ MA);

        actualMouldTemp = (int)  ((0 - 51.4)+(0.302 * meltTemp) +(1.64 * rand1[0])+   (0.201 * rand1[1]));

        System.out.println("The actual mould temperature is :" +actualMouldTemp + "       Degrees celcius" );

        //getDiff(actualMouldTemp);

        return actualMouldTemp;

 }
```

The returned value actualMouldTemp is used by a Temperature control Agent. The same returned value is used to compute the difference which is also called by the temperature control agent. The problem is that when the values are being called from another agent, Operation Agent, the value AMT is a zero. Thus the need to store them in an array and access them from there. Is this the best way to deal with this?? What other alternative is there that doesnt involve creating an array??

Comment: in your first method, getDiff(), why are you creating an instance of Computation and then not using it?

Answer (score 1):

To store in an array you need to give the array index at which the value will be stored

```
Results[0] = getDiff();

System.out.println("AMT IS "+ Results[0]);
```

Also,

- Array starts from index 0
- Try to pass the values as parameters to getDiff method

By doing Results[1] you are wasting a space... so start with 0

Comment: How do i pass the values as parameters in getDiff()?? And wht does the array I should create look like?? The one I had created is the one that was giving me zeros.

Comment: The variables actualMouldTemp and setTemp can be passed as parameters to getDiff(int actualMouldTemp, int setTemp)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see why you need the array in the first place, if you rewrite your diff() function like this:

```
public int getDiff(int targetTemp, int currentTemp) {
    int diff = (int) Math.abs(targetTemp - currentTemp);
    System.out.println("The temperature difference is : "+ diff);
    return diff;
}
```

and then use it in your calculations - you should be on your way.

Comment: I am using the class Computation as the class that handles all calculation for my JADE agents. So what happens is that the values used in getDiff() for the actualMouldTemp is a value returned by the method getAnswer() as show below:

Comment: Please look at the edition I have made to the question

Comment: If you post a complete but minimal example of the Computation class that shows your problem, it would be easier to understand the problem you are having.